# Automatically assigning User token to custom profile model django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I currently have a signal that automatically creates a Token object for a User when they sign up to the website.

I also have a custom User model, `UserProfileInfo`, in which I have a field that connects a Token to the User
`token = models.OneToOneField(Token,related_name='token',on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)`
However, I want this to be automatically assigned when the userprofileinfo is created, which happens in a signal.

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        token = Token.objects.create(user=instance)
        UserProfileInfo

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfileInfo.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.userprofileinfo.save()
```

(*the first signal creates a token, the second creates the userprofileinfo*)

I want to know how I can automatically assign a token to a user when the userprofileinfo is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the code for both tasks within one signal method.

What you could do is, create your UserProfileInfo object first and then create a Token for the user.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfileInfo.objects.create(user=instance)
        token = Token.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.userprofileinfo.save()
```

Comment: But how am I able to automatically attach the token to the userprofile model?

Comment: You don't need to, your Token is attached to User, and User to UserProfileInfo, You should be able to perform a Join on the data.

Comment: I am just a little bit confused as to how I would display it in a template

I have tried {{ request.user.token.key }}
{{ user.token.key }}, {{ user.key }}, {{ token.key }}

I am just stumped as to what I am doing wrong

Comment: So right now, your Token has a reference to User, not the other way around. if you wanted to access the token in your template, you can created a Token and assign that to your user object. There are two ways to do that,  you could override the save() method for User or you could do it in your post_save signal.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I am at a roadblock where I just do not know.

Comment: {{Token.objects.get(user=request.user)}} should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209753/discussion-between-varun-rathore-and-jeremy-lord).